# Cmake and ninja install fail with a bash script

Tags: bash, cmake

I'm doing cmake (version 3.10.2) and ninja install on my project. I defined alias in a bash script, creating shortcuts to build the code. I tried the two scenarios below.

Can anyone help me understand why the sequence in scenarioA fails and scenario B passes?

**ScenarioA:**

```
#sourcemeA.sh  
#!/bin/bash
alias exportev="export ARTIFACTORY_DIAG_SERVER=example.com:80/artifactory; export ARTIFACTORY_DIAG_PROJECT=diags-dev"  
alias gninja="cmake ../diag_gpu_main/ -DPROJECT=xxx -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=linux_gnu_x86_64_official -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DPACKAGE=xxx,yyy,zzz -DBUILD_TYPE=dbg -G Ninja"  
alias compile="ninja install"  

#end of script here

$source sourcemeA.sh  
$cd buildfolder  
$exportev  
$gninja  
$compile  
CMake Error: The source directory "xxx/buildfolder/install" does not exist.
```

**ScenarioB**

```
#sourcemeB.sh  
#!/bin/bash
alias exportev="export ARTIFACTORY_DIAG_SERVER=example.com:80/artifactory; export ARTIFACTORY_DIAG_PROJECT=diags-dev"  
function cmakee(){  
    cmake ../diag_gpu_main/ -DPROJECT=xxx -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=linux_gnu_x86_64_official -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DPACKAGE=xxx,yyy,zzz -DBUILD_TYPE=dbg -G Ninja  
}  
alias gninja="cmakee"  
alias compile="ninja install"  

#end of script here  

$source sourcemeB.sh  
$cd buildfolder  
$exportev  
$gninja  
$compile  
Build complete successfully.
```

Comment: Please provide your shell scripts exactly as they are. Some of the lines have a `$` in front, which certainly is not present in the scripts. Also, we can not see the `#!` line, and hence don't even know wheather they are interpreted as bash.

Comment: Edited the original post with full script..

Comment: I don't know `cmake` well enough to explain what is going on, but I understand now that the lines with the `$` sign are what is executed by cmake. Correct? Now, assuming from the ScenarioB case, that the `exportev` indeed correctly sets the correct environment, I would as a next step prefix each `cmake` command with `pwd; printenv; set -x; ` to get a better idea of what is going on. Also, have a look whether _cmake_ accepts some debugging option (or verbose output). Is the source directory **really** meant to b _xxx_ (three 'x')?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of this

```
-DPROJECT=xxxx
-DPROJECT=xxx
```

And i'd suggest to use functions instead of aliases

Comment: @Ivan : While the preference of using functions over aliases is certainly a good idea, I think that his does not exaplain the effect the OP sees here: In both cases, aliases are invoked in a basically correct way (`exportev`, `gninja` and `compile`), but only `gninja` makes trouble: If it expands to a function call, you get the correct result. If it expands directly to the `cmake` command itself,  it does not work, and it is understandable that the OP wants to know, why it is. Unfortunately, I'm not proficient in `cmake`, so I have no clue here.

Comment: @user1934428 i'm just trying to help) Just came to my mind, maybe it's a double quotes issue? Is there something to expand? Change double quotes to single in alias assignment.

Comment: I don't see any expansion, neither something involving backslashes in the provided code. Do you see one? Hence I would say that the quotes don't matter.